# Django reverse queryset containing all values in list

Tags: django, sqlite, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset

If I have:

```
value_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Right now I'm performing:

```
Category.objects.filter(title__values__in=value_list)
```

However, the `Category` filter runs an `OR` operation on the value list, so it selects the object if the value is in `1` OR `2` OR `3` OR `4` OR `5`.

Is there an easy way to have run an `AND` operation, so it would select all `Category` objects that contain all of the elements in the `value_list`?

e.g.) Select all `Categories` which have `values` equaling `1` AND `2` AND `3` AND `4` AND `5`. (For clarification, this means a single `value` equaling `1`, and a single `value` equaling `2` and so on...)

**Note:** We are running a double reverse lookup here, first looking in the `title` objects, then in the `value` objects.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have the `Q` objects for complex lookups for this purpose

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Category.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(title__values=x) for x in value_list))
```

This is equivalent of saying (essentially a more verbose way of saying the same thing is):

```
query = None
for x in values_list:
    if not query:
        query = Q(title__values=x)
    else:
        query &= Q(title__values=x)

qs = Category.objects.filter(query)
```

Documentation on [`Q` objects here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Thumbs up from me for another option. But wow, Django has really complicated the matter here. (Don't get me wrong, though. I love Django!)

Comment: I agree.. However, ignoring the verbose code, this evaluates to 1 query, as evaluation islazy..

Comment: @JustinBarber Actually, in your solution,it would be just 1 query to the database too..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know mine would also be only 1 query to the database. (See the comment in my answer, which was made before your comment above.) My five-year-old was needing my attention, so I shot off my previous comment in haste mostly to acknowledge yours. I just couldn't think of what to say with my son clamoring for attention at my side. Cheers.